# Mod Security2 deactivation rule only from a specified IP address

Tags: apache, ip, ubuntu-14.04, mod-security2

Is it possible to disable a rule by Mod Security2, only for one specified IP address?

Only for one specified IP addresses **&** only for one specified path ( */administrator* ) ?

I tried this:

```
<LocationMatch /administrator>
Allow from 123.456.78.999
 SecRuleRemoveById 000000
</LocationMatch>
```

But it does not work. :(

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Server and I just managed to install mod security2.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says about SecRuleRemoveById: "Removes the matching rules from the current configuration context". I think that LocationMatch opens a new configuration context for ModSecurity and this is why you approach does not work. (https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#SecRuleRemoveById)

Try the ctl-action "ruleRemovebyID" (from the same configuration context as the rule you want to remove) (https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#ctl)

```
SecRule REMOTE_HOST "@ipmatch 123.456.78.999" \
"id:12345,phase:2,t:none,pass,nolog,noauditlog,ctl:ruleRemovebyID=000000"
```

If your want to also restrict to the path /administrator you will probably need to chain a second SecRule matching the path.

Hope this helps,

Ronald